# What means the jumper field in a footprint pad properties in Altium?

Tags: pcb-design, altium, footprint, routing

I have copied a footprint to a new .PcbLib file. After doing that the field called "jumper" in the properties window for each pad has been set to 0 (for two pads) and to 1 (in six pads). I notice that later. I went to the Pcb editor and when I run the DRC I got the following error "same Jumper ID but conected to different nets). I checked the jumper field and it was there when I notice that when copying the footprint that field has been set to 0 and to 1. The error aplies only for the 1 ones. I don't undertand the Altium explanation for that field (https://www.altium.com/documentation/altium-designer/pcb-pad-properties?version=18.1#!properties). Setting them to cero solved the problem.
Why did the field autocomplete with 0 and 1 values? Which is the correct? Should I set that field to 0 for all pads in all my footprints? Whats the meaning of it?

Message: Short-Circuit Constraint: Between Pad J1-10(136.245mm,12.545mm) on Multi-Layer And Pad J1-32(121.065mm,15.085mm) on Multi-Layer Pads have the same JumperID: 1 but different Nets: (No Net) and IN_21

[image]

Comment: Altium manual : The pads used must use the same Jumper value and must also share the same net. But you used two different nets, an undefined net an the net IN_21. It seems you missed a connection in the schematic. May be a wire in the schematic is a little bit too short and does not touch the center of the pad.

Comment: My question is about the jumper. I know now I have to use the same Jumper value, what is that? What's the purpose? What's the meaning? Why all of my problems solved by changing the number?

Comment: I think the jumper value is there to avoid forbidden jumper connections, for instance the connection of two outputs without any input or jumpers with different voltages.

Comment: @Uwe so, why is this field completed with '0' in all footprints?